# How do I see the comment on a PostgreSQL constraint?

Tags: postgresql

PostgreSQL has a syntax to [COMMENT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-comment.html) on a constraint:

```
COMMENT ON CONSTRAINT` constraint_name ON table_name IS 'text'`
```

Example:

```
COMMENT ON CONSTRAINT bar_col_cons ON bar IS 'Constrains column col';
```

That tells me how to *define* comments on constraints. But how do I then *see* the comments that have been defined?

The output of `\d+` on the table includes a list of constraints, but it doesn't show the comments.

Comment: If you run `psql` with the [`-E` switch](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) it will show you all the SQL behind the various `\d` commands you run. Very convenient for quick'n'dirty tutorials on the system tables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\dd <constraint_name>` should show the comment, but does not filter on table name.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the system catalogs [`pg_constraint`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-constraint.html) and [`pg_description`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-description.html) to query comments on constraints.

Example table with comments on constraints:

```
create table test(
    id int unique,
    str text check(str <> '')
);

comment on constraint test_id_key on test is 'my comment on test_id_key';
comment on constraint test_str_check on test is 'my comment on test_str_check';
```

Select all comments on constraints of the table `test`:

```
select c.relname, t.conname, d.description
from pg_class c
join pg_constraint t on c.oid = t.conrelid
join pg_description d on t.oid = d.objoid and t.tableoid = d.classoid
where c.relname = 'test'

 relname |    conname     |         description          
---------+----------------+------------------------------
 test    | test_str_check | my comment on test_str_check
 test    | test_id_key    | my comment on test_id_key
(2 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way is to query [pg_constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/catalog-pg-constraint.html) and use the [obj_description()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-COMMENT-TABLE) function, like this:

```
select conname, obj_description(oid) as description
from pg_constraint
where conrelid = '(myschema.)mytable'::regclass;
```